# How to handle errors reliably in a shell function called as a condition?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

Using bash 4.1.5:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

foo()
{
        false
        echo "argh, I don't want to get there! What about set -e?!"
}

foo && echo "ok"
```

This yields the following output:

```
argh, I don't want to get there! What about set -e?!
ok
```

This issue occurs whenever `foo` is called as a condition (i.e inside `if`, `while`, `&&`, `||`, etc.). `foo` behaves correctly if called as a simple command.

I find this behavior surprising and quite frankly dangerous, because this means that the behavior of a bash function changes depending on how it is called. For example, even something as simple as `foo` and `foo && true` will *not* yield the same results. This is very troubling! One can only imagine how much chaos this could cause if `foo` is doing sensitive operations...

Is there any workaround I could use to avoid this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make foo() return a non-zero exit code if it fails?

```
foo(){
    return 1
    echo "argh, I don't want to get here! What about set -e?!"
}
```

Comment: This was just an example. In real-world scripts I would have to add `|| return 1` to basically all commands I execute inside functions, which is quite cumbersome and ugly. But I'm not sure I have a choice here.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is expected, and quite necessary.  Consider a function like:

```
word_is_in_file() {
   grep $1 $2 > /dev/null
}
```

Now, consider a script that uses this function (sorry, this example is a bit contrived
since a real script would probably just invoke grep directly) to make a decision:

```
if word_is_in_file $word $file; then
  do_something
else
  do_something_else
fi
```

The definition of the function may be buried in a library of shell
functions that the author never sees.  The author does not consider
the grep failure to be a failure, and would be very baffled if 
the script terminated because of it.

A way to get the semantics you desire is to do something like:

```
foo() {
   # This function will abort if errors are encountered, but 
   # the script will continue
   sh -e -c '
   false
   echo not reached'
}

foo && echo not reached
echo reached
foo
echo not reached
```

The semantics of set -e are also set to not abort the script in
the "foo && ..." case for the same reason.  It allows branching.

Comment: "The author does not consider the grep failure to be a failure, and would be very baffled if the script terminated because of it." Of course. But I'm not talking about terminating the script here: I'm talking about terminating the function.

Comment: Your solution which calls `sh` has a number of caveats that make it unusable for me: first it's an unnecessary fork+exec, and second it can't access the variables of the parent script.

Comment: "The semantics of set -e are also set to not abort the script in the "foo && ..." case for the same reason. It allows branching." Again, there would be no problem with branching if `set -e` aborted the *function*, not the *script*. This would be the expected, unsurprising behabior. But that's not what happens, and I guess I have to live with it.

Comment: @e-t172 The function can access variables which have been exported to the environment.  The fork/exec is fast, and you have no choice; running in a subshell is the only way to get the behavior you want.

Comment: If the semantics were such that functions were aborted, it would be very difficult to write stable functions as their behavior would change depending on whether set -e was in effect.   It *might* be convenient to have syntax that would allow something like: foo() -e { ... }, but you can get that with a subshell.

Comment: "If the semantics were such that functions were aborted, it would be very difficult to write stable functions as their behavior would change depending on whether set -e was in effect." That's already the case: `foo` *will* abort the script if `set -e` is in effect (`foo && true` won't). Besides, that's not a real problem since nobody in their right mind would do serious shell programming without `set -e`.

Comment: No one in their right mind would do serious shell programming ;). Your example is not quite what I was getting at; the author of the script wrote "set -e", so the semantics of the script are known to the author of the script.  But the author of foo() does not know if -e is in effect, so the semantics of foo are controlled by something external to foo.  That would be bad.  The err_return option in zsh may give you what you are looking for.